# handling controller/function in laravel 4

Tags: routes, laravel, laravel-4, codeigniter-2

I am trying to rewrite a with Laravel 4. previously I used Codeigniter. Usually I would do this in Codeigniter:

redirect('Controller/Function', 'Refresh');

and this would work on redirecting to that function of that controller. Here in laravel things seem different with all the routing happening. I saw many examples on the web and especially on the official laravel site docs & forum. I couldn't get what people are talking about.

Can someone please explain this as simple as possible?

really appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described [here](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#redirects):

`return Redirect::action('Controller@Function');`

The methods in `Redirect` send the `Location` header with appropriate values. In the case of `action` it matches the URL in `routes.php` (where you define `URL => 'Controller@Function'` pairs) and fills in parameters if specified.

The difference between these frameworks is that CodeIgniter uses implicit routing conventions by default while Laravel uses explicit ones.

Implicit means that CodeIgniter will automatically define `URL => 'Controller@Function'` pairs with the `URL` part generated from the `Controller@Function` part.

Explicit means you have to define them yourself with the added benefit that you can rename routes at will as long as you use `Redirect` to generate redirect headers and [URL](http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers) to generate URLs in your views.